# Variable textbox issue

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to fill the forms on the web page with selenium starting from the second line of the form. The textbox names in the Second line of the form are dp_2, tb_2 and tel_2. The numbers at the end of each row increase by one. E.g. dp_3, tb_3 and tel_3 etc.

Now the problem is that `for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)` when I set i to 0, it transfers all the data in the datagridview but fills it starting from line 10.

If I set the value of i to 2, it fills in from the second row, but in this case it skips the first 2 data.

Do you have a suggestion to both pass all the data and fill the form starting from the second line of the second form?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{ 
    var val1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(); //dogum tarihi
    var val2 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(); // tcno
    var val3 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(); // tel

    driver.FindElement(By.Id("dp_2" + i.ToString() )).SendKeys(val1);
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("tb_2" + i.ToString())).SendKeys(val2);
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("tel_2" + i.ToString())).SendKeys(val3);
}
```

Comment: u have to track each selenium element. First, loop all of your slelenium elements, then perform any action u want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe can use this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{ 
    var val1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i-1].Cells[0].Value.ToString(); 
    var val2 = dataGridView1.Rows[i-1].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    var val3 = dataGridView1.Rows[i-1].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

    driver.FindElement(By.Id("dp_2" + i.ToString() )).SendKeys(val1);
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("tb_2" + i.ToString())).SendKeys(val2);
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("tel_2" + i.ToString())).SendKeys(val3); 
}
```

Comment: When I change it like that; It begins from the line 21st row.

Comment: test it: for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

Comment: I have tried this. for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)  but the result hasn't changed. It begins from eleventh.

Comment: The problem has solved. with this. dp_2" + (i+2)

Answer (score 0):

The problem has solved. with `this. dp_2 + (i+2)`